# Trouble Installing SublimeLinter

Tags: sublimetext2, sublimelinter

I've been trying for the past half hour to install SublimeLinter, but to no avail.

I've thoroughly been following the instructions [here](http://sublimelinter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation.html), but I don't have the same screen that they describe.

When I type `linter` into Package Control, I am not getting the results the say I should.

Here's a screenshot.

[image: Sublime Screenshot]

Does anyone know what they may have forgotten to metion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directions you are trying to follow are for SublimeLinter 3, which is only available for Sublime Text 3. Since you're using ST2, please follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter-for-ST2#sublimelinter-v17-overview) for information on how to install and set up the plugin.